# project PCA back into original scales with explained_variance_ratio_ condition

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have 2 questions concerning PCA when using scikit.

Lets suppose I have the following data:

```
fullmatrix =[[2.5, 2.4],
             [0.5, 0.7],
             [2.2, 2.9],
             [1.9, 2.2],
             [3.1, 3.0],
             [2.3, 2.7],
             [2.0, 1.6],
             [1.0, 1.1],
             [1.5, 1.6],
             [1.1, 0.9]]
```

Now I do the PCA calculations:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA as PCA

sklearn_pca = PCA()
Y_sklearn = sklearn_pca.fit_transform(fullmatrix)
print Y_sklearn  # Y_sklearn is now the Data transformed with 2 eigenvectors

sklearn_pca.explained_variance_ratio_  # variance explained by each eigenvector
print sklearn_pca.explained_variance_ratio_

sklearn_pca.components_ # eigenvectors order by highest eigenvalue
print sklearn_pca.components_
```

**First question:**
How can I project back this Y_sklearn into the original scale? (I know we should get back the same data as of full matrix as I'm using all eigenvectors, its just to check if done right).

**Second question:**
How can I enter a threshold regarding minimum acceptable total variance coming from "sklearn_pca.explained_variance_ratio_"?. For example lets say I want to keep using eigenvectors until when i reach total explained_variance_ratio_ above 95%. In this case is easy, we just use the first eigenvector as it explains .96318131%. But how can we do this in a more automated way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: `sklearn_pca.inverse_transform(Y_sklearn)`

Second:

```
thr = 0.95
# Is cumulative sum exceeds some threshold
is_exceeds = np.cumsum(sklearn_pca.explained_variance_ratio_) >= thr
# Which minimal index provides such variance
# We need to add 1 to get minimum number of eigenvectors for saving this variance
k = np.min(np.where(is_exceeds))+1
# Or you can just initialize your model with thr parameter
sklearn_pca = PCA(n_components = thr)
```

Comment: thanks @Olologin, but when i run it it says: TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple

Comment: Now works perfect. Thank you for your answer! Also, any source you recommnend to analize the residuals of a "projected" PCA?